# Post preview doesn't correctly render ### strings

Tags: bug, questions, answers, design

When editing this tag wiki, I noticed the preview doesn't correctly render *### Features*.

> [image: screenshot]

This is how the wiki page is then rendered.

> [image: screenshot]